# How to return JavaScript from PHP file through AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How to do this?

1. We have button with onclick event, that sends a query using AJAX to PHP file.
2. PHP file has this JavaScript: `echo '<script>alert("hello");</script>';`
3. When pushing onclick event button, JavaScript doesn't work. I don't see a "hello" message.

Does anybody knows how to execute JavaScript from PHP? I need exactly this one. I know that all JavaScript should be executed on the AJAX level. But the situation demands to execute a JavaScript, that PHP returns as response.

Best regards

Comment: Are you adding the javascript to the document?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) provides the easiest interface to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute Javascript from PHP since PHP executes on the server side while JS on the client side. You need to `eval` the returned Javascript code on the client side.

You can do this in your AJAX callback function:

```
$('#yourButton').onclick(function(){
    //make your ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url : "url",
        success : function(resp){
            //resp is the javascript code sent back from PHP
            //eval it
            eval(resp);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a javascript like:

```
"alert(\"hello\");"
```

Return like this:

```
var js = ajax.r;
```

And just do:

```
eval(js);
```

But seems to me that you have a very serious architecture problem.

Comment: `js` won't be defined in the callback.

Comment: @user1330271 what, if PHP file returns this data: <script>alert("hello");</script><span id="loading"><img src="loading.gif"></span> ??

Comment: Makes no sense. How can you return javascript and a small part of html? What are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Eval will work, but be careful.

If user generated content can get into your eval statement, someone could use that to create a malicious script for your site.

Just a heads up.